# Jquery looping with lightslider plugin

Tags: jquery, html

im using this "lightslider" plugin on each of my "products" to make them into a gallary carosel. And it works. I have 10 of these products that need it.

But with my jquery code, it stacks the same code 10 times on each product. Instead of only Initiating it once per

I have tried using the jquery each function, but I think i'm missing something?

**I've put it in a picture, so it might make more sense 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAPsp.jpg**

This is the plugin
http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/

And here is a sample of my code.

```
<div class="myclass">
  <ul class="lightslider">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="myclass">
  <ul class="lightslider">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="myclass">
  <ul class="lightslider">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".lightslider").each(function () {
        $(this).lightSlider();
   });
  });
```

Comment: Can you let us know what you mean by 'stack the same code...'?

Comment: I've put in in a picture https://imgur.com/a/2Tz0c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".lightslider").lightSlider();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.6/css/lightslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.6/js/lightslider.min.js"></script>

<div class="myclass">
  <ul class="lightslider">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="myclass">
  <ul class="lightslider">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="myclass">
  <ul class="lightslider">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

There is no need to use `each`. `.lightslider` selector will select all ul's with this class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".lightslider").lightSlider();
});
```

Comment: Then it turns out like in the picture, and it doesn't work

Comment: @TobiasHeide, Run code snippet and it works as expected!

Comment: You're right it does work here. But it seems that it doesn't work the same on my page! But thanks. Now i know it should work.